# Solving a system of equations $( \frac{x^2}{2}-5x+50) ( \frac{y^2}{2}-5y+50 ) = 674^2;\;\;x+y=10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

So on my math homework I had this problem:

$\left( \frac{x^2}{2}-5x+50 \right) \left( \frac{y^2}{2}-5y+50 \right) = 674^2$

$x+y=10$

I was thinking about substituting in $x$ for $y$ because $y=10-x$ and then just expanding everything, but that seems really algebraically bashy, so is there a better way to solve this? Or if the solution is to substitute, how would I solve it?

Comment: What is 2022 or 674

Comment: Is it required that $x,y$ be integers?  If so, that should be stated in the problem.  I get $4$ solutions, two of which are integers, and two of which are complex conjugates.

Comment: @GEdgar How could you get the integer solution? My solutions are all irrational

Comment: My remark was for the 2022 version of the problem.  In the 674 version, all four solutions are irrational, two real and two complex.

Comment: Yea, $x,y$ don't need to be integers. Thanks!

Comment: This user is asking questions from a test for a math summer camp. awesomemath.org. His history of questions are from that test with slightly altered numbers. Please refrain from answering them until the test is over. (march 27 2022)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution without bash is by solving $xy$. Notice that the first equation is symmetric w.r.t. $x,y$. So, we have

$$674^2=\left( \frac{x^2}{2}-5x+50 \right) \left( \frac{y^2}{2}-5y+50 \right) \\=\frac{x^2y^2}4-\frac{5}2xy(x+y)+25(x^2+y^2)+25xy-250(x+y)+2500$$

Notice that $(x^2+y^2)=(x+y)^2-2xy$, we have
$$674^2=\left( \frac{x^2}{2}-5x+50 \right) \left( \frac{y^2}{2}-5y+50 \right) \\=\frac{x^2y^2}4-\frac{5}2xy(x+y)+25(x+y)^2-25xy-250(x+y)+2500$$

Substitute in $x+y=10$, we have

$$674^2=\frac{x^2y^2}4-25xy+2500-25xy-2500+2500$$

Or,
$$x^2y^2-200xy+100^2-1348^2=0$$
So, we have $xy=100\pm 1348$, or, $xy=-1248$ or $xy=1448$

So, $x,y$ must satisfy one of these by Vieta:

$$t^2-10t-1248=0 \text{ or }t^2-10t+1448=0$$

The first equation yields $x,y=5\pm\sqrt{1273}$ and the second equation yields $x,y=5\pm\sqrt{1423}i$.

P.S. I have checked my solution twice, and put it into number empire, but there are no integer solutions... where are they?

This is what the problem looks like now [image]

And this is the result [image]

Answer (score 1):

**Short cut**

$$\frac{[(x-5)^2+75][(y-5)^2+75]}{4}=674^2$$

and

$$x-5=5-y$$